# maven can't init log4j

Tags: maven, log4j

I know that there a lot of similar questions but I couldn't find solution which helps :)
The problem - for some reason maven started showing the message:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.maven.cli.logging.BaseSlf4jConfiguration).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

It persists despite all efforts - tried put it to several folders like "resources", "test" etc., then found out that it appears on every project. So, problem in maven. Next step was to reinstall maven from scratch - no luck again. Does anyone have ideas where the problem can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem was in log4j and self4j libs in jre/lib/ext folder. After removing them everything went back to normal.